# Android Fragments showing irregular behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have multiple fragments in my Activity. It should initiate only first fragment at start up. It initializes the second one also. More over I move from one fragment to the other though a swipe action. When I swipe from first fragment to the next, third in the row is also initiated.

I have to get data from the server and then populate that fragment. Network request is sent but not for the one for which I am sending but for the fragment next to it.

Please suggest me where I am mistaken...

Thanks in advance.

Following is the code:

**Note:** Sample code is being used, Please consider the other fragments and their layouts as the same as that for `Fragment1`.

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.fragments;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

/**
 * Constants for tabs
 */
public static final int TAB_SCORES      = 0;
public static final int TAB_PAVILION    = 1;
public static final int TAB_FRIENDS     = 2;
public static final int TAB_OTHER       = 3;
public static final int TAB_CROWD       = 4;
public static final int TAB_SOCIAL      = 5;

private List<Fragment> fragments=null;
private FragmentsAdaptor _adapter;

/** The context object. */
public static Object contextObject = null;

private TableLayout scoresTab, socialTab, pavilionTab, friendsTab, othersTab, crowdTab;

private TextView mScoresTv, mPavilionTv, mFriendsTv, mOtherTv, mCrowdTv, mSocialTv;

private HorizontalScrollView tabsLayout;
private int fragmentPosition;

public ViewPager mViewPager;

private int moveRight = 100;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

/**
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    setViews();
    addListeners();
    setTab();

    addFragments();
}

private void setViews() {
    scoresTab   = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.scores_tab);
    pavilionTab = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.pavilion_tab);
    friendsTab  = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.friends_tab);
    othersTab   = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.others_tab);
    crowdTab    = ((TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.crowd_tab));
    socialTab   = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.social_tab);

    tabsLayout = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.tabs_layout);

    mScoresTv   = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scores);
    mPavilionTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pavilion);
    mFriendsTv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.friends);
    mOtherTv    = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.other);
    mCrowdTv    = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.crowd);
    mSocialTv   = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.social);

}

private void addListeners() {
    mScoresTv.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    mPavilionTv.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    mFriendsTv.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    mOtherTv.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    mCrowdTv.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    mSocialTv.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

}

private void addFragments(){
    fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(new Fragment1(this));
    fragments.add(new Fragment2(this));
    fragments.add(new Fragment3(this));
    fragments.add(new Fragment4(this));
    fragments.add(new Fragment5(this));
    fragments.add(new Fragment6(this));

    this._adapter  = new FragmentsAdaptor(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this._adapter);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    onTabsClick(v);
}

public void onTabsClick(View v) {
    //reset layout of all the text views
    resetlayouts();

    if(v == mScoresTv) {
        if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != TAB_SCORES) {
            changeTab(TAB_SCORES);
                scoresTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                mScoresTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }
    } else if(v == mCrowdTv) {
        if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != TAB_CROWD) {
            changeTab(TAB_CROWD);
            crowdTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            mCrowdTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }
    } else if(v == mFriendsTv) {
        if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != TAB_FRIENDS) {
            changeTab(TAB_FRIENDS);
            friendsTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            mFriendsTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }
    } else if(v == mOtherTv) {
        if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != TAB_OTHER) {
            changeTab(TAB_OTHER);
            othersTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            mOtherTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }
    } else if(v == mPavilionTv) {
        if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != TAB_PAVILION) {
            changeTab(TAB_PAVILION);
            pavilionTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            mPavilionTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }

    } else if(v == mSocialTv) {
        if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != TAB_SOCIAL) {
            changeTab(TAB_SOCIAL);
            socialTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            mSocialTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        }
    }
}

private void changeTab(int tabType) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tabType);
    System.out.println("tab to change to: " + tabType);
}

private void resetlayouts(){
    scoresTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    pavilionTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    friendsTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    othersTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    crowdTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    socialTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

    mScoresTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    mPavilionTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    mFriendsTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    mOtherTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    mCrowdTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    mSocialTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));

}

private void setTab() {
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) { }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            System.out.println("setTab:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::" + position);
            int previousFragment = fragmentPosition;

            if(previousFragment < position ) {
                tabsLayout.scrollTo(tabsLayout.getScrollX() + moveRight*fragmentPosition, tabsLayout.getScrollY());
                tabsLayout.requestLayout();
            }

            if(previousFragment > position ) {
                tabsLayout.scrollTo(tabsLayout.getScrollX() - moveRight*fragmentPosition, tabsLayout.getScrollY());
                tabsLayout.requestLayout();

            }

            fragmentPosition = position;
            resetlayouts();
            System.out.println("In on tab change listener!");

            switch(position) {
                case TAB_SCORES:
                    System.out.println("scores");
                    scoresTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                    mScoresTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    //give a call to netmanager and repaint livescorescreen on the basis of selected fragment
                    break;

                case TAB_PAVILION:{
                    System.out.println("pavilion");
                    pavilionTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                    mPavilionTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    //give a call to netmanager and repaint livescorescreen on the basis of selected fragment
                    break;
                }
                case TAB_FRIENDS:{
                    System.out.println("friends");
                    friendsTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                    mFriendsTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    //give a call to netmanager and repaint livescorescreen on the basis of selected fragment
                    break;
                }
                case TAB_OTHER:{
                    System.out.println("others");
                    othersTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                    mOtherTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    //give a call to netmanager and repaint livescorescreen on the basis of selected fragment
                    break;
                }
                case TAB_CROWD:{
                    System.out.println("crowd");
                    crowdTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                    mCrowdTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    //give a call to netmanager and repaint livescorescreen on the basis of selected fragment
                    break;
                }
                case TAB_SOCIAL:{
                    System.out.println("social");
                    socialTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                    mSocialTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    //give a call to netmanager and repaint livescorescreen on the basis of selected fragment
                    break;
                }
            }
            Fragment fragment = _adapter.getFragment(previousFragment);
            if(fragment != null) 
                fragment.onPause();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**FragmentsAdapter**

```
package com.example.fragments;

import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class FragmentsAdaptor extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


private List<Fragment> fragments;
/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public FragmentsAdaptor(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

}
```

**Fragment1**

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
private Context context;

public Fragment1() {}

public Fragment1(Context contex) {
    this.context=contex;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onInflate(Activity activity, AttributeSet attrs, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onInflate(activity, attrs, savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("Fragment1.onInflate() called................");
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    System.out.println("Fragment1.onAttach() called................");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("Fragment1.onCreate() called................");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("Fragment1.onCreateView() called................");

        View root = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_screen, null);
        updateArticleView(root);

        return root;
    }


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("Fragment1.onActivityCreated() called................");
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    System.out.println("Fragment1.onStart() called................");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("Fragment1.onResume() called................");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("Fragment1.onPause() called................");
    onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    System.out.println("Fragment1.onDestroyView() called................");
    onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("Fragment1.onDestroy() called................");
    onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    System.out.println("Fragment1.onDetach() called................");
}

public void updateArticleView(View view) {

}

}
```

**Main Activity Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/tabs_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- First Tab -->

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/scores_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/scores"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:text="Scores"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="1px"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <!-- Second Tab -->

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/pavilion_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pavilion"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="25dp"
                    android:text="Pavilion"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="1px"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <!-- Third Tab -->

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/friends_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/friends"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:text="Friends"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="1px"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <!-- Fourth Tab -->

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/others_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/other"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:text="Other"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="1px"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <!-- Fifth Tab -->

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/crowd_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/crowd"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:text="Crowd"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <!-- Sixth Tab -->

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/social_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/social"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:text="Social"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs_layout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**Fragment layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relLay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:text="Fragment1 Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it by placing the following code at the end of `OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected()`

```
Fragment fragment = _adapter.getFragment(previousFragment);
if(fragment != null) {
   fragment.onPause();
}
```

I am using `onPause()` in the following way

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    onDestroyView();
}

public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    onDestroy();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    onDetach();
}

public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a known issue, that ViewPager(FragmentAdapter(Fragements)) created and destroyed according to the actual page.
I also came across with this situation, furthermore the data (Object) not referenced, because of a destroy will be collected by the GC so this is difficult.

I would use a static object at the main Activity and with the [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) method I would save and load Fragment state.

Also found another solution which concentrated on the passed data between the Fragments (A,B and passed String data) [here](http://android-er.blogspot.hu/2012/09/life-cycle-of-fragments-in-viewpager.html).

I hope one of these solutions are suitable for you!

Comment: Thanks to you @csikos.balint, I did try your suggestion however it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `setOffscreenPageLimit()` in `onCreate()` (after initializing ViewPager). The OffscreenPageLimit sets the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page. Set the minimum number of fragments you want to initiate either side.

Comment: Thanks to you @Vipul Purohit, I did try your suggestion however it didn't solve my problem.