# custom radio buttons to give functionality like tabhost

Tags: android

### How to achieve the functionality of tabHost using radiobuttons in android ?

- How to design a custom radiobuton group on the top,
- so that on click on that button like we do it in tab host ....
  functionality of displaying the activity in obtained

**tabs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdb1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tab1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdb2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tab2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <include layout="@layout/tabs"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

### screen1.java & screen2.java r other 2 activities

[image]

Comment: You can have an idea from this [question][1] about your problem.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785207/android-fragments-showing-irregular-behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1** how to create custom RadioButton ?

**Answer:**  you can apply the custom style to your RedioButton. now there are very simple way to create custom style for a UI control.
Here I show you how to crate custom style for RedioButton:

```
<style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
<item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_btn_radio</item>
```

create a drawble selector for the button state.  **res/drawable/custom_btn_radio.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />

<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_pressed" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_pressed" />

<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_selected" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_selected" />

<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
```

**Problem 2**
How to show Two activity in a single Container(Perhaps It is also be a part of Activity)
 **Answer**: There are no way to open Activities in a single Activity class. You can open multiple Fragment in a single Activity. or Other way replace your layout at runtime on radio button selection. As i know First one is good way.